# Are there any differences in meaning between these expressions

Tags: meaning

Are there any differences in meaning between these

**Unemployed** for so long, he had lost all hope
**Having been unemployed** for so long he had lost all hope

I think because of so long they are both equivalent

Comment: It would be preferable if you were to complete both sentences, so as to provide more context for the readers and ensure that we answer correctly.

Comment: You are correct; they are semantically equivalent (i.e. they mean the same).  However, there is definitely as aesthetic difference: the first is much more pleasing to the ear (and to the eye).  A good writer would always choose the former.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct; the following two sentences are semantically equivalent (i.e. they mean the same).

> Unemployed for so long, he had lost all hope.
>
> Having been unemployed for so long he had lost all hope

However, there is definitely as aesthetic difference: the first is much more pleasing to the ear (and to the eye). A good writer would always choose the former